# Infinite redirection with optional parameter and beforeEnter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am using Vue and Vue-Router. I have a route with an optional parameter called "roundNumber". Depending if the local storage have the item "numberOfRounds", I want to redirect on the first round ("/leaderboard/1") otherwise I'll redirect on "/leaderboard".

router.js

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import HomeView from "../views/HomeView.vue";
import CreateMyLeaderboard from "../views/CreateMyLeaderboard.vue";

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "Home",
      component: HomeView,
    },
    {
      path: "/leaderboard/:roundNumber?",
      name: "Create my leaderboard",
      component: CreateMyLeaderboard,
    },
    {
      path: "/help",
      name: "Help",
    },
    {
      path: "/changelog",
      name: "Changelog",
    },
    {
      path: "/about",
      name: "About",
    },
  ],
});

export default router;
```

App.vue

```
<script setup>
import { onBeforeMount, ref } from "vue";
import NavigationSection from "./components/navigation/NavigationSection.vue";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";

const router = useRouter();
const routes = ref([]);

const getRoutes = () => {
  router.options.routes.forEach((route) => {
    const routeToAdd = {
      path: route.path,
      name: route.name,
    };
    routes.value.push(routeToAdd);
  });
};

onBeforeMount(() => getRoutes());
</script>

<template>
  <header>
    <NavigationSection :routes="routes" />
    <RouterView />
  </header>
</template>
```

CreateMyLeaderboard.vue

```
<script setup>
import { Form } from "vee-validate";
import { useFormatStore } from "../stores/format.store";
import formatSchema from "../schemas/format.schema";
import FormGenerator from "../components/form/FormGenerator.vue";
import TheTab from "../components/tab/TheTab.vue";
import NavigationSection from "../components/navigation/NavigationSection.vue";
import { onBeforeMount, ref } from "vue";

const formatStore = useFormatStore();
const routes = ref([]);

const getRoutes = () => {
  for (let i = 1; i <= formatStore.getNumberOfRounds; i++) {
    const routeToAdd = {
      path: `/leaderboard/${i}`,
      name: `${i}`,
    };
    routes.value.push(routeToAdd);
  }
};

const onSubmit = (values) => {
  formatStore.setMode(values.format.mode);
  formatStore.setNumberOfRounds(values.format.numberOfRounds);
  getRoutes();
};

onBeforeMount(() => getRoutes());
</script>

<template>
  <div v-if="!formatStore.getMode">
    <Form @submit="onSubmit">
      <FormGenerator :schema="formatSchema" />
      <button type="submit">Create</button>
    </Form>
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <TheTab>Points distribution</TheTab>
    <TheTab>Players</TheTab>
    <TheTab>Round </TheTab>
    <NavigationSection :routes="routes" />
  </div>
</template>
```

I want to handle that case in the router.js (which is more logical to me) so I tried with a beforeEnter like this:

```
  beforeEnter: () => {
    const numberOfRounds = localStorage.getItem("numberOfRounds");
    if (numberOfRounds) {
      return { path: "/leaderboard/1" };
    } else {
      return { path: "/leaderboard" };
    }
  },
```

But it gives me a warning saying I am doing an infinite redirection. I would like to know how to achieve my idea in the router ideally if possible.

Thanks for helping,

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags.